# how to advertise eddystone UID using raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, eddystone

How to advertise a eddystone UID using a raspberry pi device.Using python or hci.
I have published the URL but not understading the format of UID.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will advertise  10-byte namespace identifier of 00010203040506070809, a 6-byte instance identifier of 010203040506, a zero meter Tx Power level of e7 (-25 dBm).

`hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 06 03 03 aa fe 15 16 aa fe 00 e7 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 01 02 03 04 05 06`

You actually start the advertising with:

`hciconfig hci0 leadv 3`

Note that if you are not running as root, you will need to precede the above commands with `sudo`

In terms of the format of UID, it simply contains the three fields described above.  Google defines the layout [here](https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid).

Comment: how did you manage to get hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 06 03 03 aa fe 15 16 aa fe 00 e7 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 01 02 03 04 05 06    from 00010203040506070809   along with 010203040506.What format is it.

Comment: That BlueZ command sets the bytes to advertise.  The specific bytes are based on the Eddystone-UID layout link in my answer.  The specific values of the namespace identifier and instance identifier are made up -- these values can be whatever you want, and together uniquely identify a single beacon.